# Toad / Import Utility / Import User to User still refer old User's schema in triggers

Tags: oracle, import, psql, toad

Up to now, the quickest way I know to import a schema to another database is through "Import/Export Utility" by Toad for Oracle.

However, everytime we import from schema A to schema B (choosing Import User), the triggers still refer the old schema.

For example, the import process tried to run this code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER B.CONTACT_DETAILS_bir 
 BEFORE INSERT ON A.CONTACT_DETAILS FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SELECT A.CONTACT_DETAILS_seq.NEXTVAL
   INTO   :new.id
   FROM   dual;
 END;
/
```

Needless to say, the script failed because A.CONTACT_DETAILS does not exist in the target database.

Is there anyway to avoid this mismatch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've asked the developer in charge of this area of Toad and here is his response; he's not on StackOverflow.

> The Import Utility is actually an Oracle product. Toad just gives you
>   a GUI to create the command to run it. There's no parameter for IMP
>   that I know of which will parse your triggers and change them so they
>   point to the new schema. I don't know for sure, but I don't think that
>   Oracle would consider it a bug. One way you could prevent the problem
>   is by not specifying schema names at all in your trigger code. In that
>   case, the trigger will assume that the table is in the same schema.

Comment: I guess that too... Never tried not specifying the schema name in trigger code, but that makes sense. I'll try and let you know the result